# css multiple div does not seem to work together

Tags: html, css

I have this in my css file  and html file.

```css
.prodhome-boxshadow{
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
}

.prodhome-category {
     width:22%;
     float:left;
     margin:0 1.65% 3.55%;
}
.prodhome-category img {
     max-width:60%;
     height:auto;
     margin:0 5%;
     align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="prodhome-boxshadow">
        
            <div class="prodhome-category">
                <h1>Product-title</h1>
                <img src="" />
            </div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="clearrow"></div>
```

what I get is the box shadow does not encompass the product title and image. Instead I get the box shadow display above where the products are and ends before the Producttiles are displayed.   How can I accomplish this?

Comment: for the easy fix add `overflow:auto` to div with box-shadow ... but better read the above question to understand

Comment: thank you,  I wasn't sure how to search for it, therefore I added the question, but I see now, thanks for the help